# Deep Conditional Type of a Generic in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, type-level-computation, higher-kinded-types, recursive-type

So I have this helper function that allows me to replace types based on structural matching:

```
type Replace<T, C, A> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends C ? A : T[P]
}
```

This allows me to do the following:

```
type NumberThing = { value: number }
type StringThing = Replace<NumberThing, number, string>

const a: StringThing = { value: "cenas" }
```

All is nice and dandy, until someone does this:

```
type ArrayOfNumberThing = { value: Array<number> }
```

Ok, so, I just add a new condition...

```
type Replace<T, C, A> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends C ? A : (T[P] extends Array<C> ? Array<A> : T[P])
}
```

And it types:

```
type ArrayOfNumberThing = { value: Array<number>, simpleValue: number }
type ArrayOfStringThing = Replace<ArrayOfNumberThing, number, string>
const b: ArrayOfStringThing = { value: ["cenas"], simpleValue: "still works" }
```

But this guy is stubborn, and now throws me a:

```
type CrazyNumberThing = { value: Array<Array<Array<number>>> }
```

Well, I could always do this:

```
type RecursiveArrayReplace<T, C, A> = T extends C ? A : (T extends Array<infer E> ? RecursiveArrayReplace<E, C, A> : T)
```

... which would, obviously, search deeply into the Array until it finds what it wants to replace, right? Right? Wrong:

```
Type alias 'RecursiveArrayReplace' circularly references itself.
```

And before I could wipe my tears, someone just threw me a:

```
type TupleStringNumberThing = { value: [string, number] }
```

... which is making me curl up in a fetal position unless you guys help me :(

Comment: Why isn't it written like this instead: `type ArrayOfStringThing = Replace<ArrayOfNumberThing, Array<number>, Array<string>>`?

Comment: Because that would be too easy ;) The point was to get an answer to an arbitrary deep type replacement problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your particular examples, I'd write it like this:

```
type DeepReplace<T, C, A> = T extends C ? A : T extends object ? {
    [P in keyof T]: DeepReplace<T[P], C, A> } : T;
```

This should work for all your types [including arrays/tuples if you're using TS3.1 or above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays):

```
type NumberThing = { value: number }
type StringThing = DeepReplace<NumberThing, number, string>
// type StringThing = { value: string; }

type ArrayOfNumberThing = { value: Array<number>, simpleValue: number }
type ArrayOfStringThing = DeepReplace<ArrayOfNumberThing, number, string>;
// type ArrayOfStringThing = { value: string[]; simpleValue: string; }

type CrazyNumberThing = { value: Array<Array<Array<number>>> };
type CrazyStringThing = DeepReplace<CrazyNumberThing, number, string>;
// type CrazyStringThing = { value: string[][][]; }

type TupleStringNumberThing = { value: [string, number] };
type TupleStringStringThing = DeepReplace<TupleStringNumberThing, number, string>;
// type TupleStringStringThing = { value: [string, string]; }
```

Obviously you could find other edge cases... should functions that accept/return `C` should be with functions that accept/return `A`?  These can likely be handled but it might not be worth the extra complexity if your use case doesn't need it.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgEoIDYEMDGEA8AVANFAMKECCAfFALxS5QQAewEAdgCYDOxUA-FKVABctek1acoAewBGAKwgZgvKAG8AsACgo2qAG0AClACWLKAGsIISQDNaAXWFwEyMOix4DdwiX6UAvkK0ANyamqCQUAByAK4AttIQAE64ABYmAObUqlAAbmgo0RDCLHEJiVB+YeDQAMrAiRmpGVlOSKiYODHxSU0s6YQl3YmEHPUZ5JoA9JNQ4bVjfb2ZNCq5+YXCow19QRWhGnP8iYloIADy1l1lS1mreQVFRycg2INl5CNGsa4QAGrrjzeST2B2qT1OFzq23SNxorRcbhwpGOEMupR6aT6A3RwygW3GIQ001mYORz0hCxhmOW2XuGzxlN0dl2HC+P3+D02lN2lQ0VQiRBOAC8QFcMc0VmtOeCXmTTtg5S8gYlyKqKoTDoK0CKoY1qS14G1XB1sFqRWLktTsUMRpTyITiZrhSBdYt9ZK6Y98X0mb7mSD+dBcNEfq70hbYbSAcJdN7+lBlXZ1YHaCGUBAw2HI-D2u5g6HKRGrQmcbbofapjNDvn05nKZG7tG9HGyxl-QEgA)